# Error: detached entity passed to persist - try to persist complex data (Play-Framework)

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

I have a problem with persisting data via play-framework. Maybe it's not possible to achive that result, but it would be really nice if it would work.

**Simple**: I have a complex Model (Shop with Addresses) and I want to change the shop with addresses at once and store them in the same way (shop.save()). But the error `detached entity passed to persist`occurs.

**Udate History**
05.11

- 05.11

  - update Model Shop with attribute `mappedBy="shop"`
  - update link to google user group
- 09.11

  - find a workaround, but it's ot generic
- 16.11

  - update example html form, thanks to @Pavel
  - update workaround (update 09.11) to a generic method, thanks to @mericano1
- 21.11

  - I gave up trying to find a solution and waiting for play 2.0...

**Dateil**: 
I try to cut down the problem to a minimum: 

**Model**:

```
@Entity
public class Shop extends Model {

    @Required(message = "Shopname is required")
    public String shopname;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="shop")
    public List<Address> addresses;

}
```

```
@Entity
public class Address extends Model {

    @Required
    public String location;

    @ManyToOne
    public Shop shop;
}
```

now my **Frontendcode**:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}

#{form @save(shop?.id)}

    <input type="hidden" name="shop.id" value="${shop?.id}"/>

    #{field 'shop.shopname'}
        <label for="shopName">Shop name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="${field.name}" 
            value="${shop?.shopname}" class="${field.errorClass}" />
    #{/field}

    <legend>Addressen</legend>
    #{list items: shop.addresses, as: "address"}
        <input type="hidden" name="shop.addresses[${address_index - 1}].id" value="${address.id}"/>
        <label>Location</label>
        <input name="shop.addresses[${address_index - 1}].location" type="text" value="${address.location}"/>
    #{/list}

     <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Save changes" />
#{/form}
```

I have just the Id from the Shop itself and the shopname to deliver via POST like: `?shop.shopname=foo`

The interssting part is the list of addresses and there I have the Id and the location from the address and the result would be somthin like: `?shop.shopname=foo&shop.addresses[0].id=1&shop.addresses[0].location=bar`.

Now the **Controller** part for the data:

```
public class Shops extends CRUD {

public static void form(Long id) {

    if (id != null) {
        Shop shop = Shop.findById(id);
        render(shop);
    }
    render();
}

public static void save(Long id, Shop shop) {

    // set owner manually (dont edit from FE)
    User user = User.find("byEmail", Security.connected()).first();
    shop.owner = user;

    // Validate
    validation.valid(shop);
    if (validation.hasErrors()) 
        render("@form", shop);

    shop.save();
    index();
}
```

Now the **problem**: When i change the address data the code reaches the `shop.save();` the object shop is filled with all data and everything looks fine, but when hibernate tryes to persist the data, the error `detached entity passed to persist` occurs :(

I tried to change the fetch mode, the cascadetype and i also tried:

```
Shop shop1 = shop.merge();
shop1.save();
```

Unfortunately nothing worked, either the error occurs, or no address data will be stored. 
Is there a way to store the data in that way?

If there is somthing not clear please write to me, I would be glad to give as much information as possible.

**Update 1**
I also put the problem on the [google user group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/e9c67a1927fff124)

**Update 2 + 3** 
With the help of the user group (thanks to bryan w.) and an Answer from mericano1 here I found a generic workaround.

First you have to remove `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` from attribute `addresses` in shop.class. Then you have to change the method `save` within shops.class.

```
public static void save(Long id, Shop shop) {

    // set owner manually (dont edit from FE)
    User user = User.find("byEmail", Security.connected()).first();
    shop.owner = user;

    // store complex data within shop
    storeData(shop.addresses, "shop.addresses");
    storeData(shop.links, "shop.links");

    // Validate
    validation.valid(shop);
    if (validation.hasErrors()) 
        render("@form", shop);

    shop.save();
    index();
}
```

the generic method to store the data looks like that:

```
private static <T extends Model> void  storeData(List<T> list, String parameterName) {
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        T relation = list.get(i);

        if (relation == null)
            continue;

        if (relation.id != null) {
            relation = (T)Model.Manager.factoryFor(relation.getClass()).findById(relation.id);
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(parameterName);
            buf.append('[').append(i).append(']');
            Binder.bind(relation, buf.toString(), request.params.all());
        }

        // try to set bidiritional relation (you need an interface or smth)
        //relation.shop = shop;
        relation.save();
    }
}
```

I added in Shop.class a list of **Links**, but I won't update the other code snippets, so be warned if compiling errors occur.

Comment: Possibly related: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1410

Comment: @ripper234 thank you for that hint. It's a really good problem description and leads to the point. Hopefully someone is going to fix that behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you update a complex instance in Hibernate you need to make sure it is coming from the database (fetch it first, then update that same instance) to avoid this 'detached instance' problem.

I generally prefer to always fetch first and then only update specific fields I'm expecting from the UI.

You can make your code a bit more generic using

```
(T)Model.Manager.factoryFor(relation.getClass()).findById(relation.id);
```

Comment: Thank you @mericano1 for the hint with the generic Model, it works fine. But your general answer is not really satisfying, I thought there should be a common way to achive storing complex data without this turn around. And I'm also puzzled about `merge`, it doesn't work as discribed. I though `merge` handles exactly that behavior for me.

Comment: But nevertheless I'll appreciate your answer to a given time ;)

Comment: no prob. Did you try doing a findById on the shop entity and then bind on the request.params? something like this https://gist.github.com/1372844 ( typed in nopepad.. might have to change it a bit!)

Comment: Intresting approach, I'll give it a try. By the way, where did you get this information, did you find them out by yourself? The construct `Model.Manager.factoryFor` looks "intresting" :D

Comment: Sorry, but within `byId.save` the error _detached entity passed to persist: models.Address_ occured. I think the problem is that the address data has changed and is detached. If you want to store them you need to reload/ refresh the database object and merge it with the new content. BUT it doesn't work automatically :(

Comment: With your code sample I found a nice workaround for my problem, thats why i give you 50 points, even if I dont found the "real" answer.

Comment: Thank you! :) if I find some better way to do that I'll let you know!

Comment: Since there is no more update and I was able to solve my issue with that workaround I'm closing the question.

Answer (score 3):

This will not make you happy. I've stubmled over the same error, was about to pose the same question on SO and saw yours. This thing doesn't work, it's a major bug. In the docs I've found  "since it could be tedious to explicitly call save() on a large object graph, the save() call is automatically cascaded to the relationships annotated with the cascade=CascadeType.ALL attribute." but it simply doesn't work.

I've even debugged the SQL, what happends to your (and my) associations is that they are deleted and re-associated to the parent, but they're never updated with the new values. It's something like this:

```
//Here's it's updating a LaundryList where I've modified the address and one of the laundry items
//it first updates the simple values on the LaundryList:
update LaundryList set address=?, washDate=? where id=?
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - 123 bong st2
binding parameter [2] as [DATE] - Fri Mar 11 00:00:00 CET 2011
binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - 413

//then it deletes the older LaundryItem:
delete from LaundryList_LaundryItem where LaundryList_id=?
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 413
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 407

//here it's associating the laundry list to a different laundry item
insert into LaundryList_LaundryItem (LaundryList_id, laundryItems_id) values (?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 413
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 408

//so where did you issue the SQL that adds the updated values to the associated LaundryItem??
```

I saw your workaround and I honestlly appreciate your effort, and the fact that you took the trouble to post it (as it will help people who are stuck with this) but this defeats the purpose of Rapid Development and ORM. If I'm forced to do some operations that normally should be automatic (or not even necessary, why is it deleting the old assication and associating the parent to a new one instead of simply updating that association in one go?) then it's not really "rapid" nor valid "object relational mapping".

As far as I'm concerned, they've took a perfectlly working framework (JPA) and turned it into something useless by modifiying its behaviour. In this case this refferes to the fact that JPA's `merge` call no longer does what it's supposed to, they tell you they've added they're own method called "`save`" which helps with that (why???) and that thing doesn't work the way it's described in the docs and examples on their site (more on this in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142392/play-framework-merge-action-only-works-in-the-controller-that-triggered-it)  question I've posted.

UPDATE:

Well, here's my workaround as well:

I now simply ignore to send in the ids of the updated associations to the controller, this way Play will think they're new entities to be added to the db, and when calling merge(...) and save() on their parent entity all daya will be saved correctlly. This however gets you another error: Since now, each time you modify some associations and save the parent, those associations are treated as new entities to be created (they have id=null), and thus the old ones are orphaned from their parent when saving all this, which either leaves you with a big bunch of orphaned, useless entities in the db, or forces you to write even more workaround code to clear those orphaned associated entities on a parent entity you're about to save.

UPDATE 2:

At this point, I think it's best to wait for Play 2.0, which is currentlly in Beta and will be launched soon. This is not too cool, as, to quote monsieur Bort (from memory) "you will not be able to migrate your Play 1.x projects to Play 2 directlly, but some light code copy-paste should suffice to transfer them". Copy/paste your code for the win! And to think how much time other framework makers spend making their new product version backwards compatible  !
At any rate, in their [article](http://www.playframework.org/2.0) introducing the Play 2.0 roadmap, they say that they'll replace Hibernate/JPA with some other ORM framework, and at the same time admit that they've  hacked the standard JPA implementation done by Hibernate in order to achieve... well, we all saw what that achieved. Here's the quote:

"Today, the preferred way for a Play Java application to access an SQL database is the Play Model library that is powered by Hibernate. But since it's annoying in a stateless Web framework like Play to manage stateful entities such as the ones defined in the official JPA specification, we have provided a special flavor of JPA keeping things as stateless as possible. This forced us to hack Hibernate in a way that is probably not sustainable in the long term. To address this, we plan to move to an existing implementation of stateless JPA called EBean."

This could be potential good news, as the new ORM seems more suited to their requirements, and is more likely to avoid the bad things they have now. I wish them all the luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your words, I thought I'm the only one whith this problem and looking for an answer. During my testing phase I came to the same "solution" and that worked perfectly. But I'd like to find a solution for the big problem, but maybe there is no one with play.

Comment: Yep, I feel your pain. I only tried Play on a small personal proof-of-concept project. I don't even want to imagine what would have happend if I'd have found myself in a middle of an actual Play project, finding out database updates work as they do. Check out my answer please, I've added another update.

Comment: Interesting update and I'm sure after migrate to play 2.0 I will forget all about this problem. BUT I'm pretty sure that other will come up :D

Comment: Well stay srong, and don't forget, there's other, more mature RAD frameworks out there, like Spring ROO.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the answer, because I don't know about Play, but the Shop-Address bidirectional association is not correct: The shop side must be marked as the inverse of the other side, using `@OneToMany(mappedBy="shop", ...)`.

Also, if `save` and `merge` corrspond to `Session.save` and `Session.merge` respectively, doing a save after a merge makes no sense. Save is used to insert a new, transient entity into the session. If merge has been called, it's already persistent at the time `save` is called.

Comment: After adding this command play was not able to find the address any more. I have some testdata and they dissappeared. Even in CRUD (its like a data control center in Play) are no addresses either.

The problem is, that shop.merge() dont store the new value for my address...

Comment: You need to initialize both sides of the association : each address in the shop's addresses must have its shop reference initialized to the shop.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I don't think this will solve my problem. 

What would be the correct way to update complex data like that?

Comment: A merge is normally entirely sufficient.

Comment: unfortunately no address data will be saved... 
If I debug to the point `shop.merge`everything looks great, but the log output doesn't update any table. What could be the reason that merge dosn't update the table address? Do I need to specify another parameter like (cascade=CascadeType.MERGE or smth like that?

Answer (score 1):

According to Play documentation you should provide a query string like the following:

```
?shop.addresses[0].id=123
&shop.addresses[1].id=456
&shop.addresses[2].id=789
```

I am not sure whether you provide it correctly. Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="shop.addresses[${address_index - 1}].id" value="${address.id}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but unfortunately its not working. I get the same error. The post parameter looks like that: `shop.id=1&shop.shopname=foo&shop.addresses[0].id=1&shop.addresses[0].location=bar`. Do you remember where you read this. I've never seen `address_index` before.

Comment: Look at Play documentation of [built-in tags](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/tags#list). Anyway, I don't get it how you can have the post parameter `&shop.addresses[0].id=1&` with different numbers when you put there same value `${address.id}`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. My parameter in the question are wrong and with your help I changed every list index to `smth_index`. After I did it i got the parameter described in my comment before.